# VS Code Java Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Every time I hit run on my main method in my java file, no matter what file, I get "Error: Could not find or load main class (name of the class)". I've tried uninstalling VS Code and uninstalling the rest of my Java extensions.

Comment: Have you checked the [VS Code docs on Java#Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java#_debugging)? Please [edit] your question with your Java code and your launch configuration.

Comment: try to delete the launch.json and run

Answer (score 0):

java notes

when vscode in particular starts a java program:
Error: Could not find or load main class (filename)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:(filename)

the way to fix it is:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin

and you have to set the PATH in the environment variables
The folder name (JDK) must be jdk
example:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin

then the name for the PATH and folder must be like that, but this also applies to the others.

Comment: Please write your entire answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an English-only site.

Comment: This would not have fixed the OP's problem.  The problem was that the `java` command that VScode was running could not find the OP's class.  This is a problem with the .class file or the class path, not the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Besides ... this question is 4 years old, and missing debugging details.  There is little chance that a (correct) late answer to an old, incomplete question would help anyone.